# Subroutine called again in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script something like below :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%G in ("!line!") do (
    if not "%%G" == "" (
        call :BOOTSTRAP %%G
        REM do some processing again here.
        echo Some processing...
    )
)
```

This is part of a bigger batch file. The problem I am facing is after the call is made to BOOTSTRAP subroutine, the system goes ahead and processes the next statements. But after that, the system again executes BOOTSTRAP with empty parameter!

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Add an `exit /b` after your loop

Comment: ^ this and by the way `%%G` will never be empty inside the `for` loop you posted because empty lines are skipped.

Comment: wouldn't exit /b exit the whole batch execution? I have some more statements after for loop.

Comment: rather the line above the `:BOOTSTRAP` label should have `exit /b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if I put a goto after for loop like :

```
goto cleanup

:cleanup
REM Do cleanup...
```

it works!

I didn't know that I need a goto or exit if I call subroutines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Next commented code snippet could help:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%G in ("!line!") do (
    if not "%%G" == "" (
        call :BOOTSTRAP "%%G"
        REM do some processing again here.
        echo Some processing...
    )
)
REM do some processing here

rem next goto to skip running in-line: could be `goto :eof` or `exit /B` or even `exit`
goto :anywhere
:BOOTSTRAP
  rem processing %~1, i.e. first parameter stripped out of surrounding double quotes 
  rem next `goto :eof` to return from subroutine: could be `exit /B` instead
goto :eof
```